# command to output map of cluster / node / public IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

Is there a way (without writing a script to join the data between kubectl and aws cli) to show the mappings between the cluster, private, public ips, load balancer name?

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

Shows the cluster IP, and the AWS private IP.

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

Shows the node name to public IP mapping

```
kubectl get services -o wide
```

Shows the cluster IP to ELB name mapping

But would be handy to join these with the addition of the ELB name (if it exists) into a single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but you can get information about several resources at the same time

```
kubectl get pod,svc,node -o wide
```

Comment: Thats awesome, ty!  Until I find a way to get this and map all the IPs to each other, this is the best answer :)